# Reconcile np.fromiter and multidimensional arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, lazy-evaluation

I love using `np.fromiter` from `numpy` because it is a resource-lazy way to build `np.array` objects. However, it seems like it doesn't support multidimensional arrays, which are quite useful as well.

```
import numpy as np

def fun(i):
    """ A function returning 4 values of the same type.
    """
    return tuple(4*i + j for j in range(4))

# Trying to create a 2-dimensional array from it:
a = np.fromiter((fun(i) for i in range(5)), '4i', 5) # fails

# This function only seems to work for 1D array, trying then:
a = np.fromiter((fun(i) for i in range(5)),
        [('', 'i'), ('', 'i'), ('', 'i'), ('', 'i')], 5) # painful

# .. `a` now looks like a 2D array but it is not:
a.transpose() # doesn't work as expected
a[0, 1] # too many indices (of course)
a[:, 1] # don't even think about it
```

How can I get `a` to be a multidimensional array while keeping such a lazy construction based on generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short update on the question: with `NumPy=1.23` it is now possible to do exactly what is given in the example:

```py
import numpy as np

def fun(i):
    """A function returning 4 values of the same type."""
    return tuple(4*i + j for j in range(4))

# Trying to create a 2-dimensional array from it:
a = np.fromiter((fun(i) for i in range(5)), dtype='4i', count=5)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)
```

Personally, I find it more readable to pass the datatypes directly instead of using the strings (not that `'i'` results in `int32` and not the standard `int64`):

```py
a = np.fromiter((fun(i) for i in range(5)), dtype=np.dtype((int, 4)), count=5)
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

See also the documentation of [fromiter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) which contains a similar example.

Answer (score 19):

By itself, [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) only supports constructing 1D arrays, and as such, it expects an iterable that will yield individual values rather than tuples/lists/sequences etc. One way to work around this limitation would be to use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to lazily 'unpack' the output of your generator expression into a single 1D sequence of values:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

def fun(i):
    return tuple(4*i + j for j in range(4))

a = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(fun(i) for i in range(5)), 'i', 5 * 4)
a.shape = 5, 4

print(repr(a))
# array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
#        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
#        [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
#        [12, 13, 14, 15],
#        [16, 17, 18, 19]], dtype=int32)
```