# Python v-stacking in a loop

Tags: python, performance, numpy, append, concatenation

I was going through an example in this computer-vision [book](http://programmingcomputervision.com/downloads/ProgrammingComputerVision_CCdraft.pdf) and was a bit surprised by the code:

```
descr = []
descr.append(sift.read_features_from_file(featurefiles[0])[1])
descriptors = descr[0] #stack all features for k-means
for i in arange(1,nbr_images):
  descr.append(sift.read_features_from_file(featurefiles[i])[1])
  descriptors = vstack((descriptors,descr[i]))
```

To me it looks like this is copying the array over and over again and a more efficient implementation would be:

```
descr = []
descr.append(sift.read_features_from_file(featurefiles[0])[1])
for i in arange(1,nbr_images):
  descr.append(sift.read_features_from_file(featurefiles[i])[1])
descriptors = vstack((descr))
```

Or am I missing something here and the two codes are not identical. I ran a small test:

```
print("ATTENTION")
print(descriptors.shape)
print("ATTENTION")
print(descriptors[1:10])
```

And it seems the list is different?

[image]

Comment: What do the elements of `descr` list look like?  arrays?  shape?

Comment: By the way, [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) (or even better, [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) for Python2.x) is much cheaper than [`np.arange`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right - repeatedly concatenating numpy arrays inside a loop is *extremely* inefficient. Concatenation always generates a copy, which becomes more and more costly as your array gets bigger and bigger inside the loop.

Instead, do one of two things:

1. As you have done, store the intermediate values in a regular Python `list` and convert this to a numpy array outside the loop. Appending to a `list` is *O(1)*, whereas concatenating `np.ndarray`s is *O(n+k)*.
2. If you know how large the final array will be ahead of time, you can pre-allocate it and then fill in the rows inside your `for` loop, e.g.:

   ```
   descr = np.empty((nbr_images, nbr_features), dtype=my_dtype)
   for i in range(nbr_image):
       descr[i] = sift.read_features_from_file(featurefiles[i])[1]
   ```

Another variant would be to use [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) to lazily generate the array from an iterable object, for example in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34018470/1461210).