# Convert string of nested list of digits without separator to 2D NumPy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I got a string of lists that looks like this:

```
'[[0123][1234][3456]]'
```

but I want to insert it to 2D NumPy array of ints.

The result should be `[[0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6]]`.

Is there an easy way to do it without a first to run over the string and every number cast it to an int and insert it to a list, and at the end insert it to the NumPy object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward solution you have already mentioned is to strip and split the input string using the `[]` brackets, create a nested list and turn it into a NumPy array:

```
s = '[[0123][1234][3456]]'
t = (
    s
    .strip('][')  # '0123][1234][3456'
    .split('][')  # ['0123', '1234', '3456']
)
a = np.array([[int(v) for v in u] for u in t])
```

You could use `np.fromiter` to replace the inner list comprehension:

```
a = np.array([np.fromiter(u, dtype=int) for u in t])
```

Using `np.stack` to combine the inner 1-d arrays works as well:

```
a = np.stack([np.fromiter(u, dtype=int) for u in t])
```

Similarly to [Reconcile np.fromiter and multidimensional arrays in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018470/reconcile-np-fromiter-and-multidimensional-arrays-in-python), you could first use `np.fromiter` to create a 1-d array containing all the numbers and afterwards reshape it into a 2-d array:

```
from itertools import chain

a = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(t), dtype=int).reshape(len(t), -1)
```

But I'm not sure if there would be any benefit of doing that.

Comment: and if the string is like this : `s = '[[0,12,3][1,2,34][34,5,6]]'` ? how to adapt your solution? i will also update the question

Comment: That's a different question.

Comment: And it's already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list